# Symfony Doctrine oneToMany inverse array key

Tags: symfony, doctrine

(sorry for the confusing title it's hard for me to explain in one sentence well!)

I basically have 3 entities that are connected to each other: `SlideshowSlide`, `SlideshowContent` and `Language`.
The `SlideshowContent` has the following property to link to `SlideshowSlide`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\SlideshowSlide", inversedBy="content", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $slide;
```

And the following property to link it to `Language`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Language", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $language;
```

In my `SlideshowSlide` I have the following `content` property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\SlideshowContent", mappedBy="slide", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $content;
```

The thing is, I know I can get all the `SlideshowContent` instances within a `SlideshowSlide`, with the dump something like:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => SlideshowSlide {#1052 ▼
    -id: 1
    -image: null
    -imageAlt: null
    -url: null
    -owner: Domain {#736 ▶}
    -content: PersistentCollection {#1077 ▼
      -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
      -owner: SlideshowSlide {#1052}
      -association: array:16 [ …16]
      -em: EntityManager {#381 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "slide"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#929 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#1050 ▼
        -elements: array:1 [▼
          0 => SlideshowContent {#1094 ▼
            -id: 1
            -slide: SlideshowSlide {#1052}
            -language: Language {#1039 ▶}
            -title: "test"
            -content: "test2"
          }
        ]
      }
      #initialized: true
    }
  }
]
```

The `#collection` array has an array with zero-based index keys. However, instead of that I'd like to use the `id` column of `language` as my key, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Even if it's possible, what if you have 2 SlideshowContent entities in this ArrayCollection with the same Language entity ? That just can't work at all unless the Language relation is OneToOne, and i'm not sure about it. Can you explain why would you want to do that ? I can't see a use case where that could be useful.

Comment: A slideshow slide has multiple slideshow content instances, one for every language. Every language can only appear once. Basically you need to be able to go to a view and you get all the language fields and if editing a slide and content is filled in for a specific language it has to fill that field

Comment: This sounds like Indexed Associations.
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested [indexed associations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html), and I think it does indeed what you want.
Here's my code and the resulting dumps:

```php
class A
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var B
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\B", inversedBy="as")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $b;

    /**
     * @var C
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\C", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="c_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $c;
//...
```

```php
class B
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection<A>
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\A", mappedBy="b", fetch="EAGER", indexBy="c_id")
     */
    private $as;
//...
```

Notice the `indexBy` option on the `@OneToMany` association.

```php
class C
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

}
```

The data:

```
Table A
╔════╦══════╦══════╗
║ id ║ b_id ║ c_id ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 34 ║   12 ║    2 ║
║ 35 ║   12 ║    5 ║
║ 36 ║   12 ║    6 ║
║ 37 ║   12 ║    1 ║
║ 38 ║   12 ║    5 ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Dump of the instance of B with `id = 12`:

```
B {#691 ▼
  -id: 12
  -as: PersistentCollection {#641 ▼
// ...irrelevant metadata...
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#584 ▼
      -elements: array:4 [▼
        2 => A {#552 ▼
          -id: 34
          -b: B {#586}
          -c: C {#542 ▼
            +__isInitialized__: true
            -id: 2
             …2
          }
        }
        5 => A {#541 ▼
          -id: 38
          -b: B {#586}
          -c: C {#540 ▼
            +__isInitialized__: true
            -id: 5
             …2
          }
        }
        6 => A {#539 ▶}
        1 => A {#537 ▶}
      ]
```

Without the `indexBy`:

```
B {#566 ▼
  -id: 12
  -as: PersistentCollection {#516 ▼
// ...irrelevant metadata...
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#584 ▼
      -elements: array:5 [▼
        0 => A {#552 ▼
          -id: 34
          -b: B {#586}
          -c: C {#542 ▼
            +__isInitialized__: true
            -id: 2
             …2
          }
        }
        1 => A {#541 ▼
          -id: 35
          -b: B {#586}
          -c: C {#540 ▼
            +__isInitialized__: true
            -id: 5
             …2
          }
        }
        2 => A {#539 ▶}
        3 => A {#537 ▶}
        4 => A {#523 ▶}
      ]
```

Be aware of the documented downsides of this feature:

> - You have to manage both the key and field if you want to change the index by field value.
> - On each request the keys are regenerated from the field value, and not from the previous collection key.
> - Values of the Index-By keys are never considered during persistence. They only exist for accessing purposes.
> - Fields that are used for the index by feature HAVE to be unique in the database. The behavior for multiple entities with the same index-by field value is undefined.

**I have to stress the final point: in my tests, using a non-unique value as an index results in Doctrine only loading the last object for that key. In my example, object A with id 35 is discarded when using `c_id` as an index.**

Comment: How would I do that so it uses the id column from property language?

Comment: @JoshuaBakker you can use the name of the column that stores the foreign key in you `indexBy`. I updated my answer to reflect that. This feels hacky as hell, though.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker be careful with non-unique indexes. Had to update again to stress that out.

Comment: But it wouldn't matter if there's no way a SlideshowContent record with the same Slide and Language will ever exist, right? Because in our system we made sure that would never be the case

Comment: I suppose it won't matter as long as you enforce that rule somehow. Maybe by adding a [composite unique constraint](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint).

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to understand what you did, but with the A B C I don't understand really how to use it in my system. I can access both `SlideshowSlide` and `Language` in `SlideshowContent`, and I can access `SlideshowContent` only in `SlideshowSlide`. So there's no relation inside languages as I think you'd never have to access it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197558/discussion-between-vctls-and-joshua-bakker).